# English phonemes audio database

Tags: english, resource-request, phonemes

I need an audio file database with any audio format which will contain the 44 English phonemes spoken by different speakers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From where I can get phonemes in audio format?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13027/from-where-i-can-get-phonemes-in-audio-format)

Comment: Also look at this question and its answers https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9315/does-sample-text-exist-that-includes-most-english-sounds-represented-by-the-inte the GMU speech accents archive comes close to your requirements

Comment: Thank you for your response! My question is very close to the first link that you sent, only in my problem, after the comparison, I need tell what mistakes made the speaker in his word. That's why i want to divide the word into peaces and compare with the phoneme. Is it real to do it this way?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question stating your problem as exactly as possible. Look at this answer and the links given there https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25512/automatic-sentence-segmentation-of-recorded-speech-with-text/25513#25513 although it is just about transcribing and segmenting phonemes and not about error detection.